# Adding Paypal to rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal

I want to add a donation controller with PayPal to my rails app. I want that when the user clicks the donate button, they will be presented with a modal asking them to enter their amount or select from a list of an amount. What is the simple way to accomplish this task?

Any tutorials or help will be appreciated.

Thanks for your cooperation

Comment: This [should](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Ruby-SDK) help you get started

Comment: I would highly recommend [Take My Money by Noel Rappin](https://pragprog.com/book/nrwebpay/take-my-money). You should have a deep understanding of how payment gateways work before charging people on your site. If you follow a simple tutorial and something changes that you don't understand...then what?